# How would you write this in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I'm not the best with math or programming and I'm trying to figure out how to write this in javascript. Any help would be greatly apprecieated.

```
M = P[i(1+i)^n]/[(1+i)^n -1]

M = Monthly Payments
P = Principle Amount
I = Interest Rate
N = Number of payments
```

Future thanks!

Comment: Plenty of code examples found via a simple Google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=monthly+payment+calculation+in+javascript.  You also should show what you tried and what you researched.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var P = 5;
var i = 10;
var n = 15;
var M = (P*Math.pow(i*(1 + i), n)) / (Math.pow(1 + i, n) - 1);
console.log(M)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be it:

```
P*(i*Math.pow(1+i, n))/(Math.pow(1+i, n)-1)
```

Math.pow(x, y) gives you x to the power y, you must use simple brackets "(  )" and for multyplying always use "*".